# PHP POST Loop from Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

i am new to php and i am trying to build a php quiz, that read questions and answers from the mysql db.
so far i have the following code:

```
require_once("scripts/connect_db.php");
session_start();
$_SESSION['Qid'] = 1;
if (!isset($_POST['answer'])){
    $Qid = $_SESSION['Qid'];
    echo $Qid;
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("Select * FROM qtable WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $Qid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchObject(); 
    echo $result->Q . "<br />";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM atable WHERE Qid = ? ORDER BY rand()");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $Qid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo "<form action=\"test1.php\" method=\"post\">";
    foreach ( $result as $row ) {
        if ( $row['correct'] == 1 ){
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"answer\" value=\"1\">" .$row['answer']."<br />";
        } else {
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"answer\" value=\"0\">" .$row['answer']."<br />";
        }
    }   
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"next\">";
    echo "</form>";     
}
else
{ 
    $Qid = $_SESSION['Qid'] + 1;
    echo $Qid;
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("Select * FROM qtable WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $Qid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchObject(); 
    echo $result->Q . "<br />";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM atable WHERE Qid = ? ORDER BY rand()");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $Qid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo "<form action=\"test1.php\" method=\"post\">";
    foreach ( $result as $row ) {
        if ( $row['correct'] == 1 ){
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"answer\" value=\"1\">" .$row['answer']."<br />";
        } else {
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"answer\" value=\"0\">" .$row['answer']."<br />";
        }
    }   
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"next\">";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

my idea is to increment $_SESSION['Qid'] by 1 every time i press submit so i can loop through the database, but so far i can only go up to the second row. Can anybody help or point me into the right direction on how to do this with out Jquery or AJAX.
Thanks

Comment: Your problems are twofold (at least). Jim and MattMoehring should team up, because they both describe a part of the problem. Kudos for using prepared statements, though. Most beginners for some reason grab the old api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep resetting `$_SESSION['Qid'] = 1;`

Try

```
require_once("scripts/connect_db.php");
session_start();
//$_SESSION['Qid'] = 1;

if(!isset($_SESSION['Qid']) {
    $_SESSION['Qid'] = 1;
}
```

then near the end, add the following to save the counter back to SESSION:

```
$_SESSION['Qid'] = $Qid;
```

Comment: @GolezTrol He beat me, too. We were probably editing the question while he was typing his answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Your Problem lies in the line...

```
$Qid = $_SESSION['Qid'] + 1;
```

The issue is that you never set the actual $_SESSION variable to anything other than 1 right after the session_start(); If you want the value to persist after incrementing, you should do:

```
$_SESSION['Qid'] = $Qid
```

Before the script ends.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i was able to find the answer with your help, here is the code:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_POST['answer'])){  
$_SESSION['Qid'] = 1;
echo "im in the if";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("Select * FROM qtable WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['Qid']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchObject(); 
echo $result->Q . "<br />";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM atable WHERE Qid = ? ORDER BY rand()");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['Qid']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo "<form action=\"test1.php\" method=\"post\">";
foreach ( $result as $row ) {
    if ( $row['correct'] == 1 ){
        echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"answer\" value=\"1\">" .$row['answer']."<br />";
    } else {
        echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"answer\" value=\"0\">" .$row['answer']."<br />";
    }
}   
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"next\">";
echo "</form>";   

} else {
    $Qid = $_SESSION['Qid'];
    $_SESSION['Qid'] = $Qid + 1;
    echo "im in the else";
    echo $_SESSION['Qid'];
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("Select * FROM qtable WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['Qid']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchObject(); 
    echo $result->Q . "<br />";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM atable WHERE Qid = ? ORDER BY rand()");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['Qid']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo "<form action=\"test1.php\" method=\"post\">";
    foreach ( $result as $row ) {
        if ( $row['correct'] == 1 ){
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"answer\" value=\"1\">" .$row['answer']."<br />";
        } else {
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"answer\" value=\"0\">" .$row['answer']."<br />";
        }
    }   
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"next\">";
    echo "</form>";
}
```